# Right time to purchase stock options?

Tags: stock-markets

I may be wrong here. What I have seen is that the stock price of companies like **AAPL** has already changed before the opening bell of **NASDAQ** due to earning call result or a news from the Asian market. For example, **AAPL** had a bad quarter and the price dropped by $25 after hours. When the market opens at **8:30 AM EST**, the price is already down. Setting a **stop market** or **stop limit** may not help because they don't get triggered after hours.

What is the best day and best time to buy stocks or options? What is the best day or best time to sell stocks? Is there a time in a day when the market is little stable to make such choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to time the market like this changes your investing strategy into luck. Obviously you don't know what a stock is going to do overnight or even during the day, so trying to buy or sell based on a guess is not wise. You'll be right sometimes and wrong sometimes, so whether you win or not is 50-50 in the long run.

If you think the stock has long-term growth potential, then buy it and don't worry about short-term fluctuations (or buy *more* if it goes down unexpectedly and you still think it has potential).  If you think a stock has reached its top potential, then sell it and buy something else.

Or, stick to index funds (where these short-term fluctuations cancel each other out more often) and don't try and get lucky on individual stocks.

Comment: I agree with everything that you wrote but I'd offer some nuance.  The OP mentioned earnings and options so for example, a covered call writer seeking income would be better served by 'timing' his covered call sales to coincide with an earnings announcement, as would a short put writer seeking to acquire the stock at a better price.  In either case, the reward would be greater due to the 'timing'.

Answer (score 2):

The best time to buy a stock or option is before it goes up in price.

Can you guess when the best time to sell them is?

Comment: Sell time is when it goes down. Should I watch the same in a day? But the fluctuations of up and down may not help. Is there a stable time during a day?

Comment: When there is no stock specific news and the market is calm, stocks tend to be calm.  That can happen at any time of the day.  In general, barring specific news, the first 1/2 hour to hour of the regular hours session tends to be more active due to the accumulation of overnight and morning news.